# How to get file object from file path in Concrete5?

Tags: concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I want to get thumbnail from the file inside the themes directory but `getThumbnail()` function requires me to pass a file object.

This obviously doesn't work:

```
$v = View::getInstance();
$themePath = $v->getThemePath();    
$thumbnail = $imageHelper->getThumbnail($themePath.'/images/abc.jpg', 100, 100, true);
```

So is it possible to get file object from the file path?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file exists only in the folder structure but not as concrete5 File Object, you need the `FileImporter` first:

```
use Concrete\Core\File\Importer;
$fi = new Importer();
if($fv = $fi->importIncomingFile($themePath . '/' . $filename)){
    $returnFile = \Concrete\Core\File\File::getByID($fv->getFileID());
}
```

Then you may pass that file object to the `getThumbNail()` function. The `getThumbNail()` doesn't take a path but an image object as first parameter:

```
$imageHelper = Core::make('helper/image');    
$thumbnail = $imageHelper->getThumbnail($returnFile, 300, 9999, false);
```

---

Here are all params that are taken (from the [API](http://documentation.concrete5.org/api/source-class-Concrete.Core.File.Image.BasicThumbnailer.html#67-117)):

```
/**
 * Returns a path to the specified item, resized and/or cropped to meet max width and height. $obj can either be
 * a string (path) or a file object.
 * Returns an object with the following properties: src, width, height
 * @param mixed $obj
 * @param int $maxWidth
 * @param int $maxHeight
 * @param bool $crop
 */
public function getThumbnail($obj, $maxWidth, $maxHeight, $crop = false)
```

Comment: I'm now using this on a different context and I'm trying to delete the file but it's not working like this: `$returnFile->delete();`. Isn't this supposed to work?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. This what I'm trying to do:
if($fv = $fi->import('application/files/test.pdf')) {
   $returnFile = \Concrete\Core\File\File::getByID($fv->getFileID());
}$mh->addAttachment($returnFile);
    $returnFile->delete();

Comment: Do some debug messages betweenbthe steps